# style.css is not applying to all the html pages in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, webpack-dev-server

What I'm trying to achieve is I have 2 html files

1. app/index.html
2. app/projects/erp-management-system.html

The style.css should apply to both the file but it is NOT
Can anyone help me here?

I have put muiltple html entries as below in webpack.config.js

```
let cssConfig = {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: [
        'css-loader?url=false',
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                plugins: postCSSPlugins
            }
        }
    ],
};

let config = {
    entry: './app/assets/scripts/app.js',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html",
            template: "./app/index.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'erp-management-system.html',
            template: './app/projects/erp-management-system.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            cssConfig
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you also show `cssConfig` in this question.

Comment: I have added `cssConfig`